# can multiple database connection be build using jdbi

Tags: java, database, jdbi

My requirement is too fetch data by joining tables from multiple databases.

Is their any way to setup connection with multiple databases using jbdi

Comment: Can you qualify what you mean by "multiple databases?" Is this multiple schemas on the same server? Or distinct servers?

Comment: [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org) can do just that, allowing for SQL joins across differing data (e.g. a CSV file paired with a remote SQL database, within the same query). 

Drill is really targeted at distributed 'Big-Data' multi-machine clustering, but can also be run in 'embedded-mode' from the Cli of a single machine, it's written in Java but it doesn't appear to lend itself too well to be embedded in a singular application (it's more a client-to-drill-server model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each DBI instance is tied to a single `java.sql.DataSource`, which I've only seen connect to a single database. So the answer to your question is, probably not.

You *can* however construct a DBI per database, query them separately, and join the result on your application server.

Depending on your use case (I'm assuming reporting?), it might be more appropriate to look into a data warehouse solution, and set up an ETL (extract, transform, and load) for each of your separate database to feed into the warehouse. Then you can produce reports from the warehouse without impacting performance of the other systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to inject two DBIs for two mysql data sources but I keep getting the below error:

A binding to org.skife.jdbi.v2.DBI was already configured at com.mmt.clm.ClmModule.provideDBI().
at com.mmt.clm.ClmModule.provideMmtDBI

Is there any way to inject multiple DBIs for multiple data sources

Comment: It would be best to submit this as a new question instead of an 'answer' to an old question.